# Was Entity Framework considered for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Just would like to know if you guys considered converting over to entity framework or not

Comment: Can you think of a good reason to? Neither can I.

Comment: L2S is more performant that EF. If L2S fulfills requirements of a job it is a much better choice than EF. IMO

Answer (score 3):

This is definitely one of the more liberal definitions of `feature-request` that I've come across.  Private implementation decisions are not exactly *features*; we shouldn't care any more about whether they use Linq to SQL or Entity Framework than we should about whether or not their pagination algorithm uses a Quicksort or a Merge Sort.

If it ain't broke, don't fix it.

Full disclosure: I personally use Linq to SQL in a number of apps and will convert them over to the Entity Framework when you pry the keyboard from my cold dead fingers.

Comment: The question body is different from the title... I'm going to edit to clarify.